# Как убрать скобки при выводе команды? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def repeat(ctx, *args, amount = 1):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x177121, description = args) 
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Что значит этот код:
Если я напишу >repeat привет, как дела - у меня выйдет это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать скобки в сообщении?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте все очень легко и просто.

```py
@bot.command()
async def repeat(ctx,*,args, amount = 1):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x177121, description = args) 
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

В строчке `async def repeat(ctx,*,args, amount = 1):` нам нужно разделить `*` и `args` простой запятой. Больше в коде менять ничего не нужно. **Исправленный код сверху**